# Phpinfo() shows old PHP version after update on NginX

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

After updating the PHP version on my digital ocean droplet running on Ubuntu 16.04, the PHP version my web server uses is still stuck on 5.6.

I have run commands to set alternatives and tried a couple of other solutions I found on the web to no avail.

The PHP version on the CLI is updated to 7.4, but that of the webserver won't bulge and I can't tell why.

Comment: Did you update php-fpm too?

Comment: Maybe this will help.

Comment: Yes I did. $ php-fpm -v shows I have php 7.4 installed. I think what I was doing wrong the whole time was to edit the default nginx conf file, rather than the one for the particular site I was working on. Right now, I'm having a 502 error.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was modifying the general conf file available at:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default to use PHP7.4, rather than the specific one for the website I was working on.

I did an ls command on the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory that showed I had different files for all the websites there and that was it!

I just had to modify the appropriate one. This took me weeks to do. Damn!

Answer (score 1):

First, try to update your ubuntu version. Ubuntu 18.04 is a stable version. After that execute these commands.

1. `apt install software-properties-common`
2. `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
3. `apt update && apt-get install php7.4-fpm`

   After that you have to add these lines into nginx config file.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }
```

Comment: This is what I was doing the whole time, except that I was editing the wrong nginx config file! Thank you.

Comment: Cool. If you faced any issue regarding this. Then please let me know.

Comment: Gives ` Unable to locate package php7.4-fpm`